# Text Classifier with OpenNLP

Tags: java, machine-learning, text-classification, opennlp, training-data

I am searching an implementation of a text classifier with OpenNLP in Java. The classes should be user defined, e.g., by learning from a training data set containing sentences with their class.

The only project I had found that goes into the right direction is this implentation in Scala:

https://github.com/chrischris292/template-classification-opennlp

Any recommendation for a Java based project with OpenNLP? The Maxim Entropy/Naive Bayes implementation for sentiment analysis in OpenNLP probably won't work...

Thanks

Comment: Is there someone with experience with that task in OpenNLP?

Comment: May I know the reasons for why Maxim Entropy/Naive Bayes implementation for sentiment analysis in OpenNLP probably won't work ?